# Moved Model Glue App No Longer Working

Tags: coldfusion-8, model-glue

A model glue site we use had to be moved to another physically different location.  I updated all the paths in ModelGlue.xml, ColdSpring.xml and other specific files, but I keep getting the following error.  Note: the current physical path is **jmc.divisions.medical_oncology.admin.controller.Controller**

---

**Could not find the ColdFusion Component or Interface jmc.medical_oncology.admin.controller.Controller.
Ensure that the name is correct and that the component or interface exists.**

The error occurred in E:\Inetpub\framework\ModelGlue\unity\loader\XmlConfigurationLoader.cfc: line 234
Called from E:\Inetpub\framework\ModelGlue\unity\loader\XmlConfigurationLoader.cfc: line 83
Called from E:\Inetpub\framework\ModelGlue\unity\loader\FrameworkLoader.cfc: line 98
Called from E:\Inetpub\framework\ModelGlue\unity\ModelGlue.cfm: line 116

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind!  Apparently, the system held onto some app-level caching for almost 48 hours.  It finally works now.